# PHP variable as documnet.getelementbyid var

Tags: javascript, php, innerhtml

Tried to find an answer to this but I am guzzumped here so hopefully someone can explain what is going on.

I have PHP file that echos a PHPvariable back to a xmlhttp.responseText. This variable is then assigned to a javascript variable like so:

```
var retn = xmlhttp.responseText;
```

When I do an alert of the variable like this:

```
alert(retn);
```

I am getting the correct information and all looks good. Now on the next line I am attempting to do this:

```
document.getElementById(retn).innerHTML = "test";
```

And it is not working...however if I manually type in the ID like so

```
document.getElementById("foo").innerHTML = "test";
```

Everything works...I have no idea why it will not work with the variable (which is clearly getting passed fine from the php file to function.  Anyone any ideas?

Comment: My guess is there's extra whitespace in the response text. Does `alert(retn.length)` show the expected length?

Comment: Just to show you the exact code:

Comment: xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
     
     retn = xmlhttp.responseText;
     
   alert(retn); ///returns as expected: returns: someid
  document.getElementById(retn).innerHTML = "test";//does not return
  document.getElementById('someid').innerHTML = "test";//If I do it like this it works
     
            }

Comment: Don't put code in comments, edit the question, so that you can show it with readable formatting.

Comment: To format code in SO, mark it and type Ctl-k or use the `{ }` tool from the toolbar.

Comment: Barmar....you are a star. How STUPID do I feel now...the alert was not showing a whitespace...fixes it by applying a retn.trim().  Doh, sometime you cant see the wood for the trees. Thanks very much

Comment: You should probably fix the problem in the server script that's adding extra space.